# How can I navigate into S3 bucket folders from EC2 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, boto

I would like to install some Python modules on my EC2 instance. I have the files I need for the installation on an S3 bucket. I can also connect from my EC2 instance to the S3 bucket through Python boto, but I cannot access the bucket contents to get the source files I need installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using s3cmd tools (http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) it is possible to download/upload files stored in buckets.

Comment: Thanks, works great :) . For those who view this post, you need to use the s3cmd get command to download files from S3 bucket and s3cmd sync to sync an entire directory tree

Answer (score 6):

Just in case you want to get the files in Python via boto, here's a simple example:

https://gist.github.com/1925584

And in case you don't like following links:

```
import boto
import os

def download_keys(bucket_name, dst_dir):
    """
    Very simple example showing how to download all keys in a bucket.
    Assumes key names don't include path separators.  Also assumes that
    you don't have zillions of objects in the bucket.  If you have a lot
    you would want to get several download operations going in parallel.
    """
    s3 = boto.connect_s3()
    bucket = s3.lookup(bucket_name)
    for key in bucket:
        path = os.path.join(dst_dir, key.name)
        key.get_contents_to_filename(path)
```

Comment: Might want to paste that code in your answer here, so that the answer doesn't have to rely on an external site.